# How can I make compatible SQL query between Oracle and SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, sql-server-2000, syntax-error

The following query refuses to work on Sql server whereas it runs fine on Oracle 10gR2.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
   SELECT count(*)
   FROM MYTABLE
   WHERE id IS NOT NULL
   GROUP BY id
)
```

It ends up with this message :

```
Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server error '80040e14'

Ligne 7 : syntaxe incorrecte vers ')'.
```

How can I make it compatible for both DBMS ?

Comment: Umm... TABLE is a reserved word in both DBMSs. Are you sure that exact query gives this error?

Comment: @MarkByers TABLE was just a place holder for the real name

Comment: Are there any other changes you made to  the query before posting it? Can we see the original query?

Comment: @MarkByers the query performed is exactly like the one in the post. The table name changes only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL Server requires an alias on derived tables, so...

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM ( 
   SELECT count(*) 
   FROM TABLE 
   WHERE id IS NOT NULL 
   GROUP BY id 
)  a
```

I'm not sure how to do the alias in Oracle. Also, you'll need to provide a column name for count(*) in the derived table.

Answer (score 1):

This should work in both:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id)
FROM yourtable
WHERE id IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: If I multiple fields, let's say id,foo and bar fields, how can I do ?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you are trying to accomplish, I think you could simplify this to

```
SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT id )
  FROM someTable
 WHERE id IS NOT NULL
```

which should work on both databases.

Comment: If I multiple fields, let's say id,foo and bar fields, how can I do ?

Answer (score 0):

In Sql Server this should work:

```
SELECT count(id)
FROM TABLE
WHERE id IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY id
```

Not sure if it will work in Oracle though